# Azure AD B2C error when authenticating a user through the ROPC user flow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When attempting to authenticate users through ROPC user flow, initially it worked but When i test the Endpoint with Postman i get 'The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.'
assistance needed thanks.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60ont.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That URL does not look correct.

It should resemble this:

```
https://<tenant-name>.b2clogin.com/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/<policy-name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

It looks like you are using an **incorrect** format:
`<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.b2clogin.com`

Remove '.onmicrosoft'.

See here for details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin

Comment: Although there was also a misconfiguration on the application too. thanks issue resolved.